# Get user ID from google authentication in express (passport.js)

Tags: angular, express, passport.js, backend

I'm trying to get the user.id after a user logs in, but I can't figure it out.

When I do a hard GET request in Postman (../api/users/829ug309hf032j), I get that user, but I don't know how to get the ID to set before the GET request.

app.component.ts

```
const id = // id I need of logged-in user //;

this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users/' + id).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data)
});
```

server.js

```
app.get('/api/users/:id', (req, res) => {
    User.findById(req.params.id, (err, users) => {
        res.send(users)
    })
})

app.get('/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/ask' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/answer');
  });
```

I'd like to show the user their name and only show it if they're logged in...

```
<p *ngIf="user">{{ user.name }}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passport populates the `req` object with `req.user` if the authentication is successful so just use some variation of:

```
app.get('/api/users/me', (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.json(req.user);
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(204);
  }
});
```

Comment: This returned null. 

I realized I could save the user as a local variable (currentUser) and pass that to the front end using the route you recommended (api/users/me). When I do a GET request, it returns the current user. Thanks.

Comment: Will that approach work if you have multiple users using the system simultaneously or won't it overwrite that local variable?

Comment: Do you have `app.use(passport.session());` in your express configuration?

Comment: I'm not sure it will work honestly. I'll have to do a couple other tests. Yes, passport.session is in there.